# xlwings Charts and Shapes

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Hi everyone I am using the following code:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('Book1.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets[0]


chart = sht.charts.add(left=sht.range('A1').expand().width+10, top=50, width=1000, height=450)
chart.set_source_data(sht.range('A1').expand('table'))
chart.chart_type = 'line'

chart.api[1].Axes(1).TickLabelPosition = -4134
chart.api[1].HasTitle = True
chart.api[1].ChartTitle.Text = 'My first automated plot'
chart.api[1].Axes(2).MajorGridlines.Delete()
```

and something annoying happens when I run the shapes' object command to turn off the Line around the chart:

```
xw.apps[15452].display_alerts = False
sht.shapes[0].api.Line.Visible = False
```

What I mean annoying is that the following alert (?) pops up, which "breaks" the purpose of my code i.e. to automate staff. Please see the alert below:
[Alert when I try to disable the lines.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGk6m.png)

So effectively the:

```
xw.apps[running_app_numberID].display_alerts = False
```

does not work maybe it does not refer to such an alert.

FYI, when I click ok on the message then I can enable and disable the lines around the shape-chart without any messages displayed, so I presume it is a one-time alert or something. Felix or anyone else can shed some light on this please?

My code works perfectly so i am just asking whether I can avoid this pop up message or not.

Thank you